# Determine which controller class is called in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, controller

I have multiple urls and need to identify which controller class is called.

**Edit**: All controller classes implements interface and interface method implementation in class will return something.

Basically I need to create a function which will accept url and interface method implementation will return custom data.

Answer (score 0):

You can meet your need by creating an Aspect class, then you will known which controller is called. see example below

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggerAdvice {

    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *)")
    public void controllerPointCut() {}

    @Around("controllerPointCut()")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        log.info("Enter: {}.{}() with argument[s] = {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), 
        try {
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.error("Illegal argument: {} in {}.{}()", Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()),
                    joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(), joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

You have to add this dependency to your project.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

To enable Aspect you have to add `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` in your  configuration class (annotated `@Configuration`).